# Unit testing a flask application: how to handle AssertionErrors?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Here is my test_server.py file:

```
from flask_testing import TestCase
class TestServer(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        import server
        app = server.run()
        return app

    def test_1(self):pass

    def test_2(self):pass
```

server.run does many things and ends by returning the app:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
def run():
    #many things that don't seem related to the issue
    import views
    views.run(app=app)
    return app
```

views.run declares many of the the @app.route endpoints. Here is a minimal case:

```
import flask
def run(app):
    @app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        return flask.render_template('index.html')
```

If I comment one of the two tests, everything goes fine. If I leave both of them I get:

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index

From what I understand about how this works the problem is caused because views.run is called twice. However I don't see any reason why it is the same instance that is used for both calls.

When tested "by hand" the server works fine, the problem only comes when using unit tests. The code above uses flask_testing but I had the same issue sooner with unittest.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This structure is a bit odd. Why are you defining your route functions within another function?

Comment: Because I need "app" to have the right value before I can call the @app.route decorator. That's the simplest way I could think of, but it certainly may not be the best.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Your organization look problematic. Unless you're using blueprints, I believe all routes must be unique or you'll get an error like this. Here's a [simple Flask project for Google App Engine](https://github.com/klenwell/hip-flask) that I maintain on Github. Routes are organized into [controllers](https://github.com/klenwell/hip-flask/tree/dev/controllers) and it includes [tests](https://github.com/klenwell/hip-flask/tree/dev/tests). Maybe it will help sort out your issue.

Comment: I'm looking at your project. I'm not used to work with things in the *\_\_init\_\_.py* but I have to agree it looks cleaner. Are you talking about unicity of routes for one specific app or among all the apps? If the former I don't get why mine are not unique, if the latter I don't get why I need the unicity...